# What's ths best way to select data from table

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a database in SQL Server 2008 R2, a table `t` contains a column `x`, I set a textBox to search `x` values on TextChanged event, a datagridview to view result.

My question is: what's the best way to search for `x` values if the table `t` contains many thousands rows ?

What about this :

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tTableAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select * from t where x like '" + textBox.Text + "%'";
    tTableAdapter.Fill(this.DS.t);
}
```

Comment: err, by using [Linq2Sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx)?

Comment: EDIT your typed-DataSet (XSD file). see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171903.aspx

Comment: Yeah. Linq2Sql, out of support, end of life thanks to MS pushing Entity Framework...

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you talk abou the sql layer - and your outdated choice of technolgoes that should rarele be used, i.e. a data adatper, ignoring all that has been done for .NET for the last 10 years leaves no alternative - that is a non-question becasue there is exactly ONE way to do that, i.e. by using a SQL statement that selects the fields of the table and has a filter condition.

Now, a total beginner may do that with:

> "select * from t where x='" + textBox.Text + "%'";

and make sure that he is open to any sql injection attack. An sql injection attack is a very arcane thing that most poeple are aware of, and you can find detailed information about that on google (just enter "sql injection attack" or look for "bobby tables" - a nice comic strip explaining it).

THe next step is then using better commands by using a PARAMETER that will make sure you can not get a sql injection.

The main question is why you have SQL at all, and do not use any of the SQL generating LINQ integrated frameworks that make sure the compiler is catching small things like table renames. Generally there are VERY few cases where using a data set of any kind makes sense (mostly: generic report generators that haven o clue how the tables look like at compile time).

But at the end it all runs down to SQL in a specific form, so the question is not a question at all. And "thousands of rows" is tiny data. Like really tiny.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I just set the table description above as example, but what if the table contains fields of nText type ?

Answer (score -1):

if you write your select command, create a new generic SqlTableAdapter:

```
var da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from t where x='" + textBox.Text + "%'", tTableAdapter.Connection);
da.Fill(this.DS.t);
```

**But** its Recomanded to [Edit SelectCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171903.aspx) \ [Add a query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kda44dwy.aspx) in Your Typed-DataSet, then:

```
tTableAdapter.Fill(this.DS.t, textBox.Text)
```

or:

```
tTableAdapter.FillBy(this.DS.t, textBox.Text)
```